# Javascript show more/less issue after function execution

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a “show more/less” button for a piece of text when it minimizes to 768px or below.

When resizing, the text is shortened via a media query, and the button is made visible. When the page is expanded again above 768px, the button is hidden and the full text is displayed again.

My issue is that if I resize below 768px and actually execute the function to the “show more” and then “show less” again, when expanding the window (in it's shortened state), only the shortened text is shown, and to have the full text visible I have to click “read more” again before expanding the window.

How do I get it so even after executing the function with the button press and expanding when the text is shortened: that the full text is displayed, regardless of what state it was previously in?

Hope that's not too confusing!

```js
function myFunction() {
  let dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  let moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  let btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  It was akin to an early phase of one of Jose Mourinho's exit strategies as Pochettino told how he had seen these issues looming from afar and how his players must re-establish their 'mental connection' and 'togetherness'. <span id="dots">...</span>  <span id="more"> Thoughts flicked to Christian Eriksen and Toby Alderweireld, who are running down the final year of their contracts to secure lucrative free transfers next summer. Players inside the camp with ambitions elsewhere will certainly eat away at Pochettino.</span>
</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
```

Comment: use a class with media queries

Comment: Please provide a full demo, including your CSS.

Comment: I just put the site live even though it's unfinished just to make it easier to see what I mean. http://portfolio.alexjohnweb.com

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [window resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) event to trigger a function when a user resizes the window and add/remove the same css classes you use to show/hide text in the queries. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to JS and I somewhat see what you're suggesting but with the window resize event can you set it to trigger at a certain width as opposed to just every time you resize the window? Here is the site if it helps: http://portfolio.alexjohnweb.com

Comment: Yes, the window resize just listens to resizing, and then you can add values at which you want to do something. Simple example below:

`window.addEventListener("resize", myFunction);
function myFunction() {
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var body = document.querySelect('body');
  if (w > 768) { body.classList.add('mobile') } 
  else { body.classList.remove('mobile') }
};`

And then use that in your css:
body.mobile #dots {display: none;}